# Добавление одного элемента в бд

Tags: php, sql

Написал запрос `$query= mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO Users (AcceptEmail) VALUES ('$acceptEmail')")`, но почему-то затрагивает другие таблицы и выводится ошибка

```
Field 'login' doesn't have a default value
```

это моё первое поле.

Comment: вам сообщают, что в таблице `users` есть поле `login`, оно не может быть пустым и не имеет значения по умолчанию, поэтому при вставке новой строки, вы должны указать в т.ч. и значение этого поля

Comment: @teran как я понял оно перезаписывает все значения. А как мне в бд дописать его?

Comment: что значит "перезаписывает" ? ничего она не перезаписывает, она же добавляет новую запись. А любая запись состоит из всех полей, она не может состоять только из части полей. Другое дело, что поля для которых разрешен NULL или заданы дефолтные значения при insert можно не указывать, тогда они примут эти самые дефолтные значения. Но все поля которые объявлены как обязательные - заполнять, как ни странно, обязательно

Comment: @Mike они у меня заполнены до этой части кода, просто сейчас мне нужно перезаписать поле с 0 на 1

Comment: Но вы же пишите INSERT - он вставляет _новую запись_, для модификации существующей записи существует UPDATE. только не забудьте ему указать какую именно запись вы хотите обновить (в части where), а то он обновит все

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html  - почитай и сделай сам

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, друг